# Legacy Google Apps Changing Domain Alias to Primary Domain

Tags: google-apps

I have signed up earlier for the google apps account which is now called as legacy and the primary domain has got expired. I am trying to bootstrap a startup ourselves and thought of using this legacy account. below are the steps I tried so see if I can change the primary domain. let me know if anyone of you know about any existing solutions.

1. No option to add a secondary domain because its a legacy account. Google removed the option.
2. Added our new domain as a domain alias.

Went through the GAM tool, Admin SDK.

There are couple of options which I could think off to achieve this.

1. Upgrade the google legacy account to a 30 day trial account and get the option to add a secondary domain and then make the primary domain change and downgrade. However, from what I have read in the internet, there is a risk where when I downgrade there would be only 1 license to use.
2. https://www.isaumya.com/how-to-change-primary-domain-for-google-apps-legacy-account/ here is a website telling me they have a script to run and make these changes and asking for 30 dollars.
3. https://github.com/marcelobern/Google-Admin-SDK-Domain This is another option that I came across.

I know it a sounds a bit crude but I am just trying to use a freebie till we get a funding for the startup :) Let me know if anyone of you have any solutions.

Comment: All options you listed uses the same Directory API. So they won't work :(

Comment: Hi Rakesh - did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: no where, got some people who charge around 10$ but not sure how they are able to do it

Comment: Hi Rakesh - Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you do the free trial, you will gain the ability to add a domain rather than a domain alias. However, you will not be able to downgrade back to legacy free until you remove the domain. (I tried this on an account I was willing to lose).

For your purposes I think you could get away with using the domain alias. Your users will need to sign in under the old primary domain name but your users can configure your domain alias as the default outgoing email address under settings/Accounts/Send mail as.